# How do I fix Guidewire ClaimCenter com.guidewire.pl.system.exception.UpgradeException

Tags: exception, guidewire

I am getting this exception:

"com.guidewire.pl.system.exception.UpgradeException: Unable to import: File system: roleprivileges.csv"

The file is in the import.gen folder. I recently altered it to remove a role from the initial creation. It was fine for several days and only just started happening.

I have scrubbed my DB and started fresh but I still get the problem.

Can anyone assist please.

Comment: it is difficult to say where the problem is, with so little information. If the database and the file are the same, then maybe some part of the code already changed?

Comment: Thanks Hoàng Long I discovered the problem in the .idea folder for studio. Something in there got corrupted. I put an answer to my own question.

Comment: just a question: may you compare 2 .idea folder to see what's the difference? You may use a third party tool like WinMerge (http://winmerge.org/?lang=en) to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one turned out to be a problem in studio. I replaced my .idea folder with a backup and problem went away.